# For cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$, is there a cover $\mathcal{A}$ of $X$ with $\mathcal{A}^2\subseteq \mathcal{U}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact and first countable space. For cover $\mathcal{A}$ of $X$, we use the notation 
\begin{equation*}
  \mathcal{A}^k=\{A_1\cup A_2\cup \ldots \cup A_k: A_i\in\mathcal{A} \text{ for all $1\leq i\leq k$ and } A_i\cap A_{i+1}\neq \emptyset, \forall 1< i< k\}.
\end{equation*}
Let cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ be given. Is there a cover $\mathcal{A}$ of $X$ such that $\mathcal{A}^2\prec \mathcal{U}$?. Note that $\mathcal{C}\prec \mathcal{D}$ if for every $C\in \mathcal{C}$, there is $D\in\mathcal{D}$ with $C\subseteq D$.

Comment: I imagine that in the first sentence you mean cover $\mathcal A$ and not $\mathcal V$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Thanks , I edited it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net,Thanks. I edited it.

Comment: Isn't the answer trivially yes because the cover consisting of all the one-element sets has the required property? It would be a more interesting question if you said **open** cover.

Comment: If $X$ is T$_1$ but not Hausdorff, then there is an open cover $\mathcal U$ such that there is no open cover $\mathcal A$ with $\mathcal A^2\prec\mathcal U$. Namely, if $p,q$ are two distinct points of $X$ which do not have disjoint neighborhoods, and if $\{p\}$ and $\{q\}$ are closed sets, let $\mathcal U$ be the set of all open sets $U$ such that $\{p,q\}\not\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is also Hausdorff, yes, even without first countability, because then $X$ is paracompact and even open cover $\mathcal{U}$ has an open star-refinement $\mathcal{V}$ (which is stronger than $\mathcal{V}^2 \prec \mathcal{U}$, and implies $\mathcal{V}^3 \prec \mathcal{U}$).